# How to change the border color of a text-area when clicking on a button in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

I have this textarea with a button, I want the border color to change when I click on the button, how can I achieve this?

Comment: take a look on NgClass \ NgStyle - this is probably what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

As gil mentioned, you're probably looking for [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) (since you mentioned css specifically in the tags). You can also do this with [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding). Here's an example that shows how you might do either:

```js
// In your component
emphasize = false;
toggleEmphasize() {
  this.emphasize = !this.emphasize;
}
```

```css
/* In your styles */
.emphasize {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<!-- And finally your template -->
<button (click)="toggleEmphasize()">Click Me</button>
<!-- Using ngClass -->
<textarea [ngClass]="{ emphasize: emphasize }"></textarea>
<!-- Using attribute binding -->
<textarea [class.emphasize]="emphasize"></textarea>
```

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wfkxyo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) that provides a working example.